# tilted sides when using piecewise function

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a square without using coordinates, but by defining a global function. However, I get tilted lines. Is it possible to get straight lines, such that I get a nice rectangle?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Dirac puls}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
            declare function={
              func(\x)= (\x<=-0.5) * (0)   +
               and(\x>-0.5, \x<=0.5) * (1) +
                          (\x>0.5) * (0);
            }
          ]
          \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = \(t\),
            ylabel = {\(\delta{(t)}\)},
            ymin=0,
            ymax=2,
            every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
            tick align = inside,
            clip mode = individual
          ]
          \addplot[red, domain=-1:1]{func(x)};
          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture} 
    \end{center}
 \end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

[image: tilted rectangle]

thanks in advance

Comment: Almost certainly this is an artifact from sampling. Probably the plot you are showing only sampled around 20 or 30 points on the interval to draw the graph. I don't know pgfplots, but search through the manual to see how you can increase the sampling so that 100 or more points are sampled.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks, changing `\addplot[red, domain=-1:1]{func(x)};` to `\addplot[red, domain=-1:1, samples =200]{func(x)};` eliminated my problem

Comment: @erwindenboer Please add your solution as a complete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the code line

```
\addplot[red, domain=-1:1]{func(x)};
```

to

```
\addplot[red, domain=-1:1, samples=200]{func(x)};
```

solved the problem. Using more samples makes the lines more vertical, but it also requires a longer computation time.

**Updated Code:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Dirac puls}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function={
          func(\x)= (\x<=-0.5) * (0)   +
           and(\x>-0.5, \x<=0.5) * (1) +
                      (\x>0.5) * (0);
        }
      ]
      \begin{axis}[
        axis lines = center,
        xlabel = \(t\),
        ylabel = {\(\delta{(t)}\)},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
        every axis plot/.append style={ultra thick},
        tick align = inside,
        clip mode = individual
      ]
      \addplot[red, domain=-1:1, samples=200]{func(x)};% <-- added samples=200
      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
  \end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: Dirac puls with PGFPLOTS.]